# ClickOnce installation folder URL relative

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

When deploying a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application, the installation folder URL, is there a way to make it relative to the web application directory hosting it?

For instance, for local testing I publish to http://localhost:54592. However, when this web application is deployed, it could be anything from http://www.foo.com to http://www.foo.com/MyVirtualDirectory

I would like the path to find the installer in its current location, and the application after installer has completed to reference the web app host, not the development URL.

Platform: [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010), .NET 4.0, and C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works out of the box if you stick with `*.application` as your application source. You just need to pick a folder inside your web application to publish your ClickOnce application, and the application is available from this address under your application.

For example, if copy your site to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite` and copy the ClickOnce to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\myapp` with `MyClickOnce.application` inside the ClickOnce folder.

Then you expose your website as `http://example.com` and the ClickOnce application is available under `http://example.com/myapp/MyClickOnce.application`.

In case of `setup.exe` you need to recreate the manifest after you publish it to the destination location. This is done with `mage.exe`.

Comment: So the manifest cannot be generically pointed at something like ./appname, it must actually be edited per deploy?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is so. If this is not true and someone corrects, I would be glad to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

In the Options dialog, the Manifests tab, you can check the box that says "Exclude deployment provider URL".

Then provide the URL to your user for the installation based on where you put it. When they run it, it will create and save the URL where they got it from, and always look there for updates.

Comment: Thank you, that will probably be an easier solution, I will test this weekend.

Comment: I can confirm, This works perfect for deployment on a local path. Just cleared the deploymentProvider codebase url from the *application file and set the codebase for the manifest as `.\ApplicationFiles\*.manifest`

Comment: * This was using Mage